# Save Rendered HTML to Image in Golang with Templating

Tags: html, go, render

I need to be able to build an html page and then save the rendered html output to an image. Before I switched to Go, I was accomplishing this with NodeJS and PhantomJS by building a "headless" webpage and capturing the image with a screenshot into an image file. I need to be able to do the same thing in Go. I know how to build the HTML template using the [html/template](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) package. But, I am lost on how I get essentially capture a screenshot of the rendered HTML and save it to an image with a specified width and height. This was fairly easy in PhantomJS by just calling the 'Render' method and passing the location of the image to save to. But, I can't find anyway to do this in Go.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check out https://github.com/sourcegraph/webloop

Comment: Call PhantomJS from Go. There is no headless browser in Go (jet.)